# Linking to another package with R inline

Tags: gcc, r, rcpp

I have a C++/Rcpp function the I need to compile and link to the pomp package to get access to a random number generator.  I can get the header file included but how to I get it to link to the compiled code?

```
CppColonized<-cxxfunction(
  sig=signature(x="numeric", t="numeric", params="numeric", dt="numeric"),
  plugin='Rcpp',
  includes = sprintf("#include <Rmath.h>\n#include <math.h>\n#include\"%s\"", 
    base:::system.file("include/pomp.h",package="pomp")),
  body=Code,verbose=T)
```

The code uses the reulermultinom function in the pomp package and when I evaluate it it gives the error

> undefined reference to `reulermultinom(int, double, double*, double, double*)

The commands being issued are

> g++
>   -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-211~1.1/include"   -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-211~1.1/library/Rcpp/include"
>   -O2 -Wall  -c file2f752742.cpp -o file2f752742.o g++ -shared -s
>   -static-libgcc -o file2f752742.dll tmp.def file2f752742.o
>   C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-211~1.1/library/Rcpp/lib/libRcpp.a
>   -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-211~1.1/bin -lR

Is seems like there should be a -lpomp or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the documentation for `cxxfunction()` and `getPlugin()` in package [inline](http://cran.r-project.org/package=inline).

You need to fill in proper -I... and -L... flags.  The `sprintf()` hack helps for the header, it doesn't give you the library location.

Also, yesterday's hint about using rcpp-devel still holds. You got three high-quality replies there today. so why not use it.  I think we have examples for this in the mailing list archives too.

Comment: I've now cross-posted on the mailing list, but I like this platform better for these kinds of questions particularly because it is easier for other people to find answers if they come with the same questions.

Comment: Your call. Romain, Davor, Doug, ... do not follow this forum.